# Can't connect from Ubuntu to Windows Shared Printer

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, printer

I have a printer connected to a PC running Windows 7 Home.

I added the printer from Ubuntu using the Windows 7 computer name. It prompts for a username and password, I entered my Windows 7 username and password, but it comes back with "Not Authorised, the password may be incorrect".

The username and password are correct though. I've also turned off the Windows 7 firewall.